# Wedge product verification

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to verify/show that:

$$T^*(F^\sigma) = (T^*F)^\sigma$$

I have that the alternating tensor, $A: L^k \to L^k$ is given by the fact that

$$AF = \sum_\sigma \mathop{\mathrm{sgn}} \sigma\, F^\sigma$$

Comment: What is $F^\sigma$? What is $T$? What have you tried?

Comment: I am a bit lost on how to go about it

Comment: F is a k-tensor on W (not necessarily alternating), and T is a linear transformation T: V--> W

Comment: Ok. No just compute: For $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in V$ we have $T^*(F^\sigma)(v_1, \ldots, v_k) = F^\sigma(Tv_1, \ldots, Tv_k) = \cdots$ ... can you see it?

Comment: it makes sense, but i can't say it polished

Comment: can i just say, by some linearity/interchanging

Comment: ... ${} = F(Tv_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, Tv_{\sigma(k)}) = (T^*F)(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)}) = (T^*F)^\sigma(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$. That's it (if I got your definitions right).

Comment: OK, but can you put a polished answer, so I can also reward you with points?

Comment: What's AB and can you also include the definitions of T* and (-)^sigma?

Comment: AB means "Allzeit bereit" - the german scout motto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have for every $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in V$ exploiting the definitions of $T^*$ and $(-)^\sigma$ given by 
\begin{align*}
   T^*F(v_1, \ldots, v_k) &= T(Fv_1, \ldots, Fv_k)\\
   F^\sigma(w_1, \ldots, v_k) &= F(w_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, w_{\sigma(k)})
\end{align*}
that
\begin{align*}
  (T^*F^\sigma)(v_1,\ldots, v_k) &= F^\sigma(Tv_1, \ldots, Tv_k)\\
           &= F(Tv_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, Tv_{\sigma(k)})\\
           &= (T^*F)(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})\\
           &= (T^*F)^\sigma(v_1,\ldots, v_k)
\end{align*}

AB,